# Integrating Ory Hydra OAuth Provider with HashiCorp Vault for Authentication

Tags: oauth-2.0, hashicorp-vault, hashicorp, ory, ory-hydra

I'm currently in the process of deploying a Vault instance by HashiCorp for secure storage and management of sensitive data. To enhance security, I intend to utilize our in-house Ory Hydra OAuth provider for authentication. However, I'm uncertain about the steps required to integrate Ory Hydra with Vault for this purpose.

So currently I am using Ory Hydra backed OAuth2 to secure my apis. Now I want to deploy a Vault instance and there are many out of the box services provided by Vault from major cloud providers but i am finding it difficult to integrate it with my Ory Hydra.

Any implementation suggestions would be a great help